# How do I display error message using custom button?

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

When the user clicks a button called "convert to service catalogue" it should trigger the creation of a new record. In some instances, this will fail, because the user logged in clicking the button does not have the privileges to perform the action.

How can I ensure an error message comes up when the record creation has not occured?

At this moment in time it takes me to a page that says "URL No Longer Exsists". This happens if the record creation has been successful and failed.

Below is the code for my button.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var result = sforce.apex.execute("ProductAction","convertToService",

{product2:"{!Product2.Id}"}); 
window.location.href = '/'+result[0].Id+'/e';
```

And below is the code for my apex class that links to the button.

```
global class ProductAction {
WebService static String convertToService(Id product2) {
    string result; // Return a string telling us if this worked or not
    Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user profile Id
    Id CurrentUser = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user Id

    Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to profile Ids
    for (Profile p: [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator']) {// Get the System Administrator profile
        allowedProfiles.add(p.Id); // Add them to the set
    }

    Set<Id> allowedUsers = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to store User Ids
    for (User u: [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005w0000004j93kAAA' OR Id = '005w0000004Noi6']) {//Select Joy Palmer and Andy McGregor Id's and select Jeremey Sharp and Mark O'Leary once they're in SF}
        allowedUsers.add(u.Id);// Add them to the set
    }
    Product2 prod = [SELECT Convert_to_Service_catalogue__c, R_D_Service_Owner__r.id , Project_Owner__r.Id From Product2 WHERE Id = :product2]; // Get the product

    if( //If...
        (currentUser == prod.R_D_Service_Owner__r.id) || // They own it
        (currentUser == prod.Project_Owner__r.id) || // They own it 
        (allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)) || //They're a system admin
        (allowedUsers.contains(currentUser))// They're a specific user
        ) {
            //Do stuff!
            prod.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;

            UPDATE prod;

            result = 'Success!';

        }   
    else {// Otherwise...
          // Do nothing
          result = 'Go Away!';
        }  
       // Return a message
       return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Quick note: if you are returning a `string`, but trying to access a property on the string (`result[0].Id`), you'll always get a null result. Just `result[0]` will get you the id in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the returned string from your function. If the record was inserted and returned, your function should return a valid Id. If the function fails, either return an error code, or message.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var result = sforce.apex.execute('TestClass', 'TestFunction', {successful: true});

// Check result in console window 
console.log(result[0]); 

// If this result starts with a string equal to the id key for the object type you are accessing, relocate the browser to that page 
if (result[0].startsWith('001')) {
    window.location.href = '/' + result[0] + '/e';
} else {
    // Otherwise, show the error message to the viewer 
    alert(result[0]);
}
```

Here's a class which emulates the class you posted. Passing a boolean to it controls what it returns, either an error or an Id.

```
global class TestClass {
    WebService static String TestFunction(Boolean successful) {
        return successful ? '0013B000008bjem' : 'Error: No Such Record Found'; 
    }
}
```

There may be better ways to do this, such as returning an object containing the result, and an error object, with some extra information. This is how the `connection.js` library handles calls such as `update`. It's worth taking a look at how they structure the return values from such calls to see how you should be structuring your code, but the method above should work as a band-aid.